# Update should not be done when the checkbox is disabled

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I have two pages, one is admin and another one is faculty. Admin allocates subject to faculty. Faculty only want to select there required hours only. My issue is that I don't want to perform update query for disabled check box. I have tried the below code, but it is updating for disabled check box too.

```
  using (SqlConnection con2 = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings
    ["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
    {
    foreach (GridViewRow r in Gv1.Rows){
     if  ((((
     (((CheckBox)(Gv1.Rows[r.RowIndex].FindControl("chkHour1"))).Checked == true 
|| ((CheckBox)(Gv1.Rows[r.RowIndex].FindControl("chkHour1"))).Checked == false)
|| (((CheckBox)(Gv1.Rows[r.RowIndex].FindControl("chkHour2"))).Checked == true || ((CheckBox)(Gv1.Rows[r.RowIndex].FindControl("chkHour2"))).Checked == false)
|| (((CheckBox)(Gv1.Rows[r.RowIndex].FindControl("chkHour3"))).Checked == true || ((CheckBox)(Gv1.Rows[r.RowIndex].FindControl("chkHour3"))).Checked == false)
|| (((CheckBox)(Gv1.Rows[r.RowIndex].FindControl("chkHour4"))).Checked == true || ((CheckBox)(Gv1.Rows[r.RowIndex].FindControl("chkHour4"))).Checked == false)
|| (((CheckBox)(Gv1.Rows[r.RowIndex].FindControl("chkHour5"))).Checked == true || ((CheckBox)(Gv1.Rows[r.RowIndex].FindControl("chkHour5"))).Checked == false)
    ))))
    {
      SqlCommand comm;
      CheckBox aa;
      bool hour1 = (r.FindControl("chkHour1") as CheckBox).Checked;
      bool hour2 = (r.FindControl("chkHour2") as CheckBox).Checked;
      bool hour3 = (r.FindControl("chkHour3") as CheckBox).Checked;
      bool hour4 = (r.FindControl("chkHour4") as CheckBox).Checked;
      bool hour5 = (r.FindControl("chkHour5") as CheckBox).Checked;
      string subject1 = ddlsubj.SelectedValue;
      string subject2 = ddlsubj.SelectedValue;
      string subject3 = ddlsubj.SelectedValue;
      string subject4 = ddlsubj.SelectedValue;
      string subject5 = ddlsubj.SelectedValue;
      string datedif = r.Cells[0].Text;
      aa=(CheckBox)sender;
      con2.Open();
      comm = new SqlCommand();
      comm.Connection = con2;
      comm.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
      if (aa.Enabled==false)
      {
       comm = new SqlCommand("UPDATE test 
                              SET aa=false 
                              when subject1=CASE WHEN (@hour1)= 'false' THEN NULL
                              ELSE @subject1 END,
                              subject2=CASE WHEN (@hour2)= 'false' THEN NULL 
                             ELSE @subject2 END,
                             subject3=CASE WHEN (@hour3)= 'false' THEN NULL 
                             ELSE @subject3 END,
                             subject4=CASE WHEN (@hour4)= 'false' THEN NULL 
                             ELSE @subject4 END,
                             subject5=CASE WHEN (@hour5)='false' THEN NULL 
                             ELSE @subject5 END,
                             hour1 = CASE WHEN (@hour1)= 'false' THEN 'false' 
                             ELSE 'true' END, 
                             hour2 = CASE WHEN (@hour2)= 'false' THEN 'false' 
                             ELSE 'true' END, 
                             hour3 = CASE WHEN (@hour3)= 'false' THEN 'false' 
                             ELSE 'true' END , 
                             hour4 = CASE WHEN (@hour4)= 'false' THEN 'false' 
                             ELSE 'true' END , 
                             hour5 = CASE WHEN (@hour5)= 'false' THEN 'false' 
                            ELSE 'true' END  where datedif=@datedif", con2);
     }
       else
       {
                   comm = new SqlCommand("update test set aa=true 
                           when subject1=CASE WHEN (@hour1)= 'false' THEN NULL 
                           ELSE @subject1 END,
                           subject2=CASE WHEN (@hour2)= 'false' THEN NULL 
                           ELSE @subject2 END,
                           subject3=CASE WHEN (@hour3)= 'false' THEN NULL 
                           ELSE @subject3 END,
                           subject4=CASE WHEN (@hour4)= 'false' THEN NULL 
                           ELSE @subject4 END,
                           subject5=CASE WHEN (@hour5)='false' THEN NULL 
                           ELSE @subject5 END,
                           hour1 = CASE WHEN (@hour1)= 'false' THEN 'false' 
                           ELSE 'true' END, 
                           hour2 = CASE WHEN (@hour2)= 'false' THEN 'false' 
                           ELSE 'true' END, 
                           hour3 = CASE WHEN (@hour3)= 'false' THEN 'false' 
                           ELSE 'true' END , 
                           hour4 = CASE WHEN (@hour4)= 'false' THEN 'false' 
                           ELSE 'true' END , 
                           hour5 = CASE WHEN (@hour5)= 'false' THEN 'false' 
                            ELSE 'true' END  where datedif=@datedif", con2);
    }
    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@subject1",subject1);
    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@subject2", subject2);
    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@subject3", subject3);
    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@subject4", subject4);
    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@subject5", subject5);
    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@hour1", hour1);
    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@datedif", datedif);
    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@hour2", hour2);
    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@hour3", hour3);
    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@hour4", hour4);
    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@hour5", hour5);
    comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con2.Close();
       }
      } 
     }
```

Comment: Your If condition seems to be confusing and seems to meet for any scenario.

Comment: from where sender object is coming

Comment: **Am new to asp.net i tried these to do update for only enabled check box can u suggest some idea**

Comment: grid view Check box only its coming

Comment: I'd say: think of it! You don't need to create two different sql commands. You have to create only one which expects `subjects` and `hours` with their respective values...

Comment: ...and, you should consider removing the huge IF-statement at the beginning. It is checking that all checkboxes are either true OR false (which they always are), which totally eliminates it's entire purpose, since the statement will ALWAYS be true!

Comment: so what can do for that

Comment: What unholy mind concocted this code? This is far too long and far too confusing, I'd recommend simplifying it and refactoring out into multiple methods, that will make your debugging task considerably easier. Is there also a reason why you're constructing the SQL manually, and not using a stored procedure / ORM like Entity Framework?

Comment: *hour1 = CASE WHEN (@hour1)= 'false' THEN 'false'*  Is essentially the same as *hour1 = @hour1*. Skip all the CASES on your hours, they do nothing but add complexity. You should really read out all your values to your UI model and update based on that. This way you can just do ONE SINGLE update without all your conditions.

Comment: How about subject it will take

Comment: You control in your UI that subject can't be updated if the corrosponding hour-field is not checked. If thats not enough and you want more business-logic, you convert your UI-data to a database model object first (a new class that you make with all the table-properties), and there you can make sure not to set subject if the hour-field is false. Then, after doing that, you pass that model to a function that generates a clean and simple update based on the model values.

Comment: Are you trying to do this: If one of the checkbox is checked, then update the DB for that checkbox?

Comment: yes am doing like these only

Comment: Convert hour1, .. hour5 to BIT. Use T-SQL boolean values. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177603.aspx

Comment: Did you not understand my comment? Are there any concepts you need me to elaborate on? It will solve all your issue in a clean way, but it's not a ready-to-use solution. You will have to do a little work and rethink your approach, but it will help you in the long run.

Answer (score 1):

You would want to first remove the IF statement as it is not needed. It is checking, as others have said, for both true OR (||) false and it will always be true.

Second, do not see anywhere where you check for .Enabled == False
This may be for what you are looking.

Comment: **how can make that update only for enabled check box and not for the disabled check box**

Answer (score 1):

According to your code if check box is disabled you perform one query and if check box enabled you perform another query

```
if (aa.Enabled==false)
{

}
else{

}
```

if you don't want to perform on disabled check boxes remove below part

```
if (aa.Enabled==false)
{

}
```