# Error in button control and checkbox

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to update my test table for storing the value in database. I want to update only the enabled check box value not the disabled check Box value. I have tried the code below but it's showing an error:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button' to
>   type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBox' .

---

```
 <asp:GridView ID="Gv1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnRowDataBound="Gv1_RowDataBound" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" CssClass="mGrid1">
            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="datedif" HeaderText="Day/Hour" SortExpression="datedif" />
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Hour1">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkColumn1" runat="server" OnClick="Check_Click(this)" />
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkHour1" runat="server" Checked='<%# bool.Parse( Eval("hour1").ToString()) %>' Enabled='<%# Eval("hour1").ToString().Equals("False") %>'
                            OnCheckedChanged="CheckBox1_CheckedChanged" OnClick="Check_Click(this)" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Hour2">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="ChkColumn2" runat="server" OnClick="Check_Click(this)" />
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkHour2" runat="server" Checked='<%# bool.Parse( Eval("hour2").ToString()) %>' Enabled='<%# Eval("hour2").ToString().Equals("False") %>'
                            OnCheckedChanged="CheckBox6_CheckedChanged" OnClick="Check_Click(this)" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Hour3">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkColumn3" runat="server" OnClick="Check_Click(this)" />
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkHour3" runat="server" Checked='<%# bool.Parse( Eval("hour3").ToString()) %>' Enabled='<%# Eval("hour3").ToString().Equals("False") %>'
                            OnCheckedChanged="CheckBox3_CheckedChanged" OnClick="Check_Click(this)" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Hour4">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkColumn4" runat="server" OnClick="Check_Click(this)" />
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkHour4" runat="server" Checked='<%# bool.Parse( Eval("hour4").ToString()) %>' Enabled='<%# Eval("hour4").ToString().Equals("False") %>'
                            OnCheckedChanged="CheckBox4_CheckedChanged" OnClick="Check_Click(this)" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Hour5">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkColumn5" runat="server" OnClick="Check_Click(this)" />
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkHour5" runat="server" Checked='<%# bool.Parse( Eval("hour5").ToString()) %>' Enabled='<%# Eval("hour5").ToString().Equals("False") %>'
                            OnCheckedChanged="CheckBox5_CheckedChanged" OnClick="Check_Click(this)" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
            <FooterStyle BackColor="#990000" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#990000" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <PagerStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" ForeColor="#333333" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <RowStyle BackColor="#FFFBD6" ForeColor="#333333" />
            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Navy" />
            <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#FDF5AC" />
            <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4D0000" />
            <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FCF6C0" />
            <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#820000" />
        </asp:GridView>
```

---

```
 using (SqlConnection con2 = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
            {

                foreach (GridViewRow r in Gv1.Rows)
                {
                    if (
                        (
                        (
                        (
                           (((CheckBox)(Gv1.Rows[r.RowIndex].FindControl("chkHour1"))).Checked == true || ((CheckBox)(Gv1.Rows[r.RowIndex].FindControl("chkHour1"))).Checked == false)
                        || (((CheckBox)(Gv1.Rows[r.RowIndex].FindControl("chkHour2"))).Checked == true || ((CheckBox)(Gv1.Rows[r.RowIndex].FindControl("chkHour2"))).Checked == false)
                        || (((CheckBox)(Gv1.Rows[r.RowIndex].FindControl("chkHour3"))).Checked == true || ((CheckBox)(Gv1.Rows[r.RowIndex].FindControl("chkHour3"))).Checked == false)
                        || (((CheckBox)(Gv1.Rows[r.RowIndex].FindControl("chkHour4"))).Checked == true || ((CheckBox)(Gv1.Rows[r.RowIndex].FindControl("chkHour4"))).Checked == false)
                        || (((CheckBox)(Gv1.Rows[r.RowIndex].FindControl("chkHour5"))).Checked == true || ((CheckBox)(Gv1.Rows[r.RowIndex].FindControl("chkHour5"))).Checked == false)
                        )
                        )
                        )
                        )
                    {
                        CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)sender;
                        bool hour1 = (r.FindControl("chkHour1") as CheckBox).Checked;
                        bool hour2 = (r.FindControl("chkHour2") as CheckBox).Checked;
                        bool hour3 = (r.FindControl("chkHour3") as CheckBox).Checked;
                        bool hour4 = (r.FindControl("chkHour4") as CheckBox).Checked;
                        bool hour5 = (r.FindControl("chkHour5") as CheckBox).Checked;
                        string datedif = r.Cells[0].Text;
                        object subject1 = DBNull.Value, subject2 = DBNull.Value, subject3 = DBNull.Value, subject4 = DBNull.Value, subject5 = DBNull.Value;
                        if (hour1)
                        {
                            subject1 = ddlsubj.SelectedValue;
                        }
                        if (hour2)
                        {
                            subject2 = ddlsubj.SelectedValue;
                        }
                        if (hour3)
                        {
                            subject3 = ddlsubj.SelectedValue;
                        }
                        if (hour4)
                        {
                            subject4 = ddlsubj.SelectedValue;
                        }
                        if (hour5)
                        {
                            subject5 = ddlsubj.SelectedValue;
                        }
                        SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand();
                        comm.Connection = con2;
                        comm.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                        con2.Open();
                        if (chk.Enabled && chk.Checked==true)
                        {
                            comm = new SqlCommand("UPDATE test SET subject1=@subject1,subject2=@subject2,subject3=@subject3,subject4=@subject4,subject5=@subject5,hour1 = CASE WHEN (@hour1)= 'false' THEN 'false' ELSE 'true' END, hour2 = CASE WHEN (@hour2)= 'false' THEN 'false' ELSE 'true' END, hour3 = CASE WHEN (@hour3)= 'false' THEN 'false' ELSE 'true' END , hour4 = CASE WHEN (@hour4)= 'false' THEN 'false' ELSE 'true' END , hour5 = CASE WHEN (@hour5)= 'false' THEN 'false' ELSE 'true' END  where datedif=@datedif", con2);
                        }
                        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@subject1", subject1);
                        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@subject2", subject2);
                        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@subject3", subject3);
                        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@subject4", subject4);
                        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@subject5", subject5);
                        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@hour1", hour1);
                        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@datedif", datedif);
                        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@hour2", hour2);
                        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@hour3", hour3);
                        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@hour4", hour4);
                        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@hour5", hour5);
                        comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        con2.Close();
                    }
                }

            }
```

And these is my (check box) sender files.

```
protected void CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < Gv1.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)Gv1.Rows[i].Cells[0].FindControl("chkHour1");
                if (chk.Checked == true)
                {
                    chk.Enabled = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    chk.Enabled = true;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: This is asp.net (web forms), not MVC

Comment: yes its not a mvc,its an web forms only

Comment: Can you provide your errors ?

Comment: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button' to type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBox'.

Comment: If this is same question you have asked yesterday http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30319411/update-should-not-be-done-when-the-checkbox-is-disabled , then no need to make new thread  of it,

Comment: I have clearly explained my requirement in these above code.I want to more specific of my requirement for that only i upload these queston

Comment: can you show sender declaration here :
`CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)sender`

Comment: protected void CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e){}

Comment: see in these code i have declared the checkbox

Comment: in your second code sample where you didn't show function declaration and for `Check_Click` too please

Comment: That is java script boss

Comment: sorry about that, confusion with the  OnClientClick attribute on ASP buttons.
but still you didn't provide the declaration for `sender` in you second sample

Comment: protected void CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < Gv1.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)Gv1.Rows[i].Cells[0].FindControl("chkHour1");
                if (chk.Checked == true)
                {
                    chk.Enabled = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    chk.Enabled = true;
                }
            }
        }

Comment: in that code you will see boss

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78302/discussion-between-emmanuel-m-and-ravinther-m).